# How to display the recieved editorstate of draftjs from backend in my react-component?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-redux, draftjs

I have the following json in my redux store:

```
{
article:{
__v0:0,
_id:"5a573965d495833744d71f46",
draftcontent:"{\"entityMap\":{},\"blocks\":[{\"key\":\"6s7sp\",\"text\":\"IamBatman\",\"type\":\"unstyled\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}}]}",
title:"Batman",
type:"",
userId:"5a39538ee3d05642efdaf1dc"
},
}
```

where draftcontent is the content made with draftjs . This is fetched from the backend and now I want to render this draftcontent as Editorstate of draftjs with read only property .  So basically I need a way to get these article from my redux store to my  react component and then render the title as well as the draftcontent .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the part of your store via props to your editor component.

```
<MyEditor article={storeSample.article} />
```

After that you can use [`createWithContent`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state.html#createwithcontent) and [`convertFromRaw`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#convertfromraw) methods in the `constructor` method of this component and initiate draft-js component with content this way:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  const content = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(props.article.draftcontent);
  const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(content))

  this.state = {
    editorState: editorState
  };
}
```

In the `render` method you should set `readOnly` and `editorState` properties for draft-js `Editor` component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container-root">
      <h1>{this.props.article.title}</h1>
      <Editor
        readOnly={true}
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this._handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check the working demo (without redux for simplifying) in the hidden snippet below:

```js
const {Editor, convertFromRaw, EditorState} = Draft;

const storeSample = {
  article:{
    __v0:0,
    _id:"5a573965d495833744d71f46",
    draftcontent:"{\"entityMap\":{},\"blocks\":[{\"key\":\"6s7sp\",\"text\":\"IamBatman\",\"type\":\"unstyled\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}}]}",
    title:"Batman",
    type:"",
    userId:"5a39538ee3d05642efdaf1dc"
  }
};

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(props.article.draftcontent)))

    this.state = {
      editorState: editorState
    };
  }
  
  _handleChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-root">
        <h1>{this.props.article.title}</h1>
        <Editor
          readOnly={true}
          editorState={this.state.editorState}
          onChange={this._handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor article={storeSample.article} />,           document.getElementById('react-root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.7.0/Draft.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.10.0/Draft.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: yes that works fine with your  storesample but when i console.log my storesample it shows this =>  Object {_id: "5a573965d495833744d71f46", draftcontent: "{"entityMap":{},"blocks":[{"key":"6s7sp","text":"d…ineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}]}", title: "D", type: "", userId: "5a39538ee3d05642efdaf1dc"…} so when i pass this as props to MyEditor like this => <MyEditor article={this.props.article}/> I get this error "uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token U"  . I am unable to resolve this json . @Mikhail Shabrikov

Comment: It is difficult to remotely determine what the problem is. It looks like the string that is stored in the `draftcontent` property is invalid JSON.